# LINQ: combining join, group by and select value

Tags: c#, linq, join, linq-to-sql, group-by

I have a query that combines a join and a group but when i try to join another table with prices i dont get any results.

Im trying to sum all hours (db.WorkpaperHours), group them by work type (db.WorkpaperTypes), get that types unit (db.Units) and get that work types price (db.InvoicePrices).

[image]

```
    var articleList = (from wp in db.Workpapers
    join wh in db.WorkpaperHours on wp.Id equals wh.WorkpaperId
    join wt in db.WorkpaperTypes on wh.WorkType equals wt.Id
    join u in db.Units on wt.Unit equals u.Id
    join ip in db.InvoicePrices on wt.Id equals ip.ArticleId //<--- this line

    where wp.InvoiceId == Id

    group wh by new
    {
        wt.Id,
        wh.WorkType,
        wt.Name,
        wt.Hour,
        wt.Vehicle,
        wt.FixedPrice,

        u.UnitName,
        UnitId = u.Id,
        Price = ip.Price
    }
    into grp
    select new InvoiceArticleList
    {
        Name = grp.Key.Name,
        NewId = grp.Key.WorkType,
        Hours = grp.Sum(p => p.Hours),
        WorkName = grp.Key.Name,

        Price = grp.Key.Price,
        FixedPrice = grp.Key.FixedPrice,


        IsHour = grp.Key.Hour,
        IsVehicle = grp.Key.Vehicle,
        UnitId = grp.Key.UnitId,
        UnitName = grp.Key.UnitName
    });
```

My problem is when i try to get the price from the table InvoicePrices that have these values:

1. InvoiceId(int) (should match WorkpaperTypes.Id)
2. ArticleId(int) (should match WorkpaperTypes.Id)
3. Price(decimal) (the value i want to fetch)

**The InvoiceArticleList model**

```
public class InvoiceArticleList
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NewId { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public string WorkName { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public bool FixedPrice { get; set; }

    public bool IsHour { get; set; }
    public bool IsVehicle { get; set; }

    public int UnitId { get; set; }
    public string UnitName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not still clear, what do you want to achieve through LINQ and where are you stuck?

Comment: Edited and hope that i explained the problem better.